# EXC_BAD_ACCESS code=2 error on custom class initialization in Xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, ios7, lldb

I'm attempting to initialize a custom class in my view controller to manage the data. Unfortunately the app crashes during the loading. I'm running Xcode 5.02 with the lldb debugger. The error I get is

```
Thread 1: EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=2, address=0xbf7ffffc)
```

The error shows up on the first line (-(void)...) of the function

```
    -(void)setDateOfErgPiece:(NSDate *)date
{
    self.dateOfErgPiece = date;

    if(self.dateOfErgPiece) {
        // Date Formatter. So Date is displayed correctly
        NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
        [dateFormatter setDateStyle:NSDateFormatterShortStyle];
        [dateFormatter setTimeStyle:NSDateFormatterNoStyle];
        // Set value
        self.dateOfErgPieceString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [dateFormatter stringFromDate:self.dateOfErgPiece]];
    }

}
```

That method is called when the object is initialized by

```
-(id)initWithDate:(NSDate *)date
{
    self = [super init];

    if(self) {
        [self setDateOfErgPiece:date];
    }

    return self;
}
```

The (NSDate *)date value in the above init method is received from this method

```
-(ErgNewDataEntryLogic *)ergPieceData {
    if(!_ergPieceData) _ergPieceData = [[ErgNewDataEntryLogic alloc] initWithDate:[NSDate date]];
    return _ergPieceData;
}
```

What is causing this error? If you need more information I'd be happy to provide it. Thank you so much!

Comment: For any EXC_BAD_ACCESS errors, you can usually track these error with use of  NSZombieEnabled.

Comment: may your object deallocated some where or before fetch dateArray you may called initWithDate

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know if this is exactly the problem or not, but this is certainly a major problem:

```
-(void)setDateOfErgPiece:(NSDate *)date {
    self.dateOfErgPiece = date;
    // ...
```

`self.dateOfErgPiece = date;` is exactly equivalent to `[self setDateOfErgPiece:date];`.

So, as the first line of the method, the method is calling itself.  Infinite recursion.

This should be changed to the following...

```
-(void)setDateOfErgPiece:(NSDate *)date {
    _dateOfErgPiece = date;
    // ...
```

The other references to `self.dateOfErgPiece` within the method seem to be okay, because they look to be calling the getter:

```
[self dateOfErgPiece];
```